# How does rxjs observable perform compare to $watch in Angularjs 1.X?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I've heard from  various ng-speakers how $watch is dangerous for performance of your application. I was wondering if anyone has compared performance of Rxjs' Observable against $watch in an AngularJS application. I know that Observables is going to be part of Angular 2.

Comment: I'd like to know more about it as well

Answer (score 25):

The two mechanisms of observing changes are inherently different.

`$watch` is a brute force, pull-based mechanism. Where the observer is active and (generally) needs to visit each observed object / expression after any change happened. Surely the more to observe the slower the whole process.

`Observable` implements a push-based mechanism. Observer is passive and gets notified when something changed. Properly implemented it allows much more intelligent propagation of changes.

---

From what I know, using `Observable`s in angular 2.0 is optional, but advised. Moreover, angular 2.0 is going to implement one-directional data flow similar to [flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). Data changes propagate only downwards in DOM -- a component can directly observe / depend on data of their ancestors but not their descendants. After a change there is a guarantee that only some subtree of DOM needs update. In most cases this subtree will be much smaller than the whole DOM.

There is [**a great video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQM0K6YG18s) from 2015 ng-conf benchmarking angular 1.x, react and angular 2.0. *(not sure if it uses Observables though)*

---

One last thing about `Observable`: it offers way more than the above description and it is a great way of dealing with asynchronous events.